Could not open +page.svelte in the editor
Randomly started getting this error on my Svelte projects recently when using the code inspector to open up files. Have no idea how to resolve. It only affects files with special characters in the name.

Could not open +page.svelte in the editor.
When running on Windows, file names are checked against a safe file name pattern to protect against remote code execution attacks. File names may consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods, dashes, slashes, and underscores.


I think the tags are incorrect.  I don't think this is a Svelte issue, but a tooling issue.  Tag the tool.

Got the same random feeling when having this

I logged an issue on the Github page and they have identified the issue and are working on a fix: https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/issues/943
